# Is Times Roman a font?

Tags: fonts, typography

I've been studying the practices of the late Massimo Vignelli, and his "A Few Basic Typefaces" has my attention.  However, the fifth typeface on the list is Times Roman, which I can't find anywhere.  Is it the same thing as

Comment: Your question seems incomplete. Please [edit] it.

Comment: "Times New Roman" is one of the most common fonts.

Comment: "Times" is an original font, designed for (guess) the newspaper *The Times*. Stuff like "Times New Roman" are modern derivates. Any visit to Wikipedia can tell you that.

Comment: This is not 'Times New Roman', it is Times Roman.

Comment: "This"???  What isn't Times New Roman?  How are we supposed to know that? Please don't post questions which require the power of telepathy in order to decipher them. Edit your question please, or it will just end up attracting close votes, and downvotes.

Comment: The answer of course is "no" right? It's a typeface ;)

Comment: "Times Roman" is the name given to the releases of Times New Roman issued for Linotype printing systems, and digital descendants thereof. See Walter Tracy, Letters of Credit. (I guess an analogy would be if Apple "presented" a release of Microsoft Office for Macs with a slightly different name but with Microsoft's approval and it was basically the same but with a few slight differences).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A typeface = forms and spacings of a set of characters as an artist has them created.

A font = technical package that makes possible to use the typeface. Mostly fonts are today computer software, but surely metallic or other material fonts are still available.

Linotype sells computer fonts. Their Times family contains a font named Times Roman. I cannot say how much it differs from Times New Roman which is in Monotype's cataloque and has been there since 1932. I guess that they are both based on the same older typeface which is adapted for newspaper printing. But this is only a guess. At least the capital C seems different.